# Get base url from string with Regex and Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get the base url from a string (So no window.location).

- It needs to remove the trailing slash
- It needs to be regex (No New URL)
- It need to work with query parameters and anchor links

In other words all the following should return `https://apple.com` or `https://www.apple.com` for the last one.

- `https://apple.com?query=true&slash=false`
- `https://apple.com#anchor=true&slash=false`
- `http://www.apple.com/#anchor=true&slash=true&whatever=foo`

These are just examples, urls can have different subdomains like `https://shop.apple.co.uk/?query=foo` should return `https://shop.apple.co.uk` - It could be any url like: `https://foo.bar`

The closer I got is with:

```
const baseUrl = url.replace(/^((\w+:)?\/\/[^\/]+\/?).*$/,'$1').replace(/\/$/, ""); // Base Path & Trailing slash
```

But this doesn't work with anchor links and queries which start right after the url without the `/` before

Any idea how I can get it to work on all cases?

Comment: You could add `#` and `?` to your negated character class. Try `^https?:\/\/[^#?\/]+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLamLd/1)

Comment: Do you need to use regex for some reason?  Or do you just want the protocol and hostname?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `#` and `?` to your [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). You don't need `.*` because that will match until the end of the string.

For your example data, you could [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
^https?:\/\/[^#?\/]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLamLd/1/)

```js
strings = [
"https://apple.com?query=true&slash=false",
    "https://apple.com#anchor=true&slash=false",
    "http://www.apple.com/#anchor=true&slash=true&whatever=foo",
    "https://foo.bar/?q=true"
];

strings.forEach(s => {
    console.log(s.match(/^https?:\/\/[^#?\/]+/)[0]);
})
```

Comment: Definitely the best answer, however it fails in case the user enters a different protocol like `file://` any idea on how to catch everything until # or ? or third / (after the two on http://) ?

Comment: @Costantin You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to list what you would allow to match, for example `^(?:https?|file|ftp):\/\/[^#?\/]+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLamLd/2)

Answer (score 4):

You *could* use Web API's built-in [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for this.  URL will also provide you with other parsed properties that are easy to get to, like the query string params, the protocol, etc.

Regex is a painful way to do something that the browser makes otherwise very simple.

I know that you asked about using regex, but in the event that you (or someone coming here in the future) really just cares about getting the information out and isn't committed to using regex, maybe this answer will help.

```js
let one = "https://apple.com?query=true&slash=false"
let two = "https://apple.com#anchor=true&slash=false"
let three = "http://www.apple.com/#anchor=true&slash=true&whatever=foo"

let urlOne = new URL(one)
console.log(urlOne.origin)

let urlTwo = new URL(two)
console.log(urlTwo.origin)

let urlThree = new URL(three)
console.log(urlThree.origin)
```

Comment: I didn't want to use new Url because it fails with a wrong protocol like `file://` and is not supported on old browsers. It fails giving "null" as a string so if you want to catch it you should check for url != "null" instead of if (url) or similar.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks. I used in one line:  `new URL(my_url).origin`

Answer (score 0):

This will get you everything up to the .com part. You will have to append .com once you pull out the first part of the url.

```
^http.*?(?=\.com)
```

Or maybe you could do:

```
myUrl.Replace(/(#|\?|\/#).*$/, "")
```

To remove everything after the host name.

Comment: It doesn't work. `"https://apple.co.uk/a/#anchor"` returns `https://apple.co.uk/a` and it often keeps the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

```
    const baseUrl = url.replace(/(.*:\/\/.*)[\?\/#].*/, '$1');
```